Using AuthGuard in application level giving errors
I have below auth guard
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService,
    private reflector: Reflector
) { }

canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {

    // ALLOW PUBLIC
    const authMetaData = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<string[]>('authorized', [
        context.getHandler(),
        context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (authMetaData?.includes('SkipAuthCheck')) {
        return true;
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const apiKey = request.headers['api-key'];
    const apiKeysFomEnv = this.configService.get<string[]>('API_KEYS');
    const even = (key) => key === apiKey;

    if (apiKeysFomEnv.some(even)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}

im using above auth guard in main.ts as below
 const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalGuards(new AuthGuard());
  await app.listen(3000);

but im getting below error

Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554) auth.guard.ts(11, 9): An
argument for 'configService' was not provided.

is there any way to resolve this ?
Thanks!

You've defined your constructor as taking 2 parameters, but then call new AuthGuard with no parameters.
